# Fastlane upload to App Store fails in non-interactive mode even with API key

Tags: ios, fastlane

I am using Fastlane in a GitLab CI environment. I am using an API key and have successfully uploaded my app to TestFlight. However, it fails when uploading the app to the App Store. The build uploads successfully, but it fails when waiting for a response after sending the metadata. Here are the relevant snippets:

```rb
# Fastfile

lane :get_app_store_connect_api_key do
  ensure_env_vars(
    env_vars: [
      'APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY'
    ]
  ) 
  app_store_connect_api_key(
    key_id: "**********",
    issuer_id: "********-****-****-****-************",
    key_content: "#{ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY"]}".gsub('\n', '\\n'),
    in_house: false,
  )
end

...


  desc "Push a new release channel build to the App Store."
  lane :release do
  
    build_release()

    appstore(
      api_key: get_app_store_connect_api_key
    )

  end
```

```
LOG

[17:22:47]: ----------------------
[17:22:47]: --- Step: appstore ---
[17:22:47]: ----------------------
[17:22:47]: Successfully loaded '/Users/********/builds/qVPSw-s1/0/********/********/client/ios/fastlane/Deliverfile' 
[17:22:47]: No values defined in './fastlane/Deliverfile'
[17:22:47]: Creating authorization token for App Store Connect API
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
|                    deliver 2.181.0 Summary                    |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
| api_key                              | ********               |
| screenshots_path                     | ./fastlane/screenshots |
| metadata_path                        | ./fastlane/metadata    |
| app_version                          | 1.1.0                  |
| username                             | ********        |
| app_identifier                       | com.********.app       |
| ipa                                  | Runner.ipa             |
| platform                             | ios                    |
| edit_live                            | false                  |
| use_live_version                     | false                  |
| skip_binary_upload                   | false                  |
| skip_screenshots                     | false                  |
| skip_metadata                        | false                  |
| skip_app_version_update              | false                  |
| force                                | false                  |
| overwrite_screenshots                | false                  |
| submit_for_review                    | false                  |
| reject_if_possible                   | false                  |
| phased_release                       | false                  |
| reset_ratings                        | false                  |
| team_id                              | ********|
| dev_portal_team_id                   | ********|
| run_precheck_before_submit           | true                   |
| precheck_default_rule_level          | warn                   |
| ignore_language_directory_validation | false                  |
| precheck_include_in_app_purchases    | true                   |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------+
[17:22:52]: Making sure the latest version on App Store Connect matches '1.1.0'...
[17:22:54]: Successfully set the version to '1.1.0'
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/description.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/keywords.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/release_notes.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/support_url.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/marketing_url.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/promotional_text.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/name.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/subtitle.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/privacy_url.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/en-US/apple_tv_privacy_policy.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/copyright.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/primary_category.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/secondary_category.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/primary_first_sub_category.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/primary_second_sub_category.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/secondary_first_sub_category.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/secondary_second_sub_category.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/first_name.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/last_name.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/phone_number.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/email_address.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/demo_user.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/demo_password.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Loading './fastlane/metadata/review_information/notes.txt'...
[17:22:54]: Verifying the upload via the HTML file can be disabled by either adding
[17:22:54]: `force true` to your Deliverfile or using `fastlane deliver --force`
[17:22:57]: Does the Preview on path './fastlane/Preview.html' look okay for you?
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               Lane Context                                                               |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM                   | ios                                                                                                 |
| PLATFORM_NAME                      | ios                                                                                                 |
| LANE_NAME                          | ios release                                                                                         |
| SIGH_PROFILE_TYPE                  | app-store                                                                                           |
| MATCH_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_MAPPING | {"com.********.app"=>"match AppStore com.********.app"}                                             |
| IPA_OUTPUT_PATH                    | /Users/********/builds/qVPSw-s1/0/********/********/client/ios/Runner.ipa                        |
| XCODEBUILD_ARCHIVE                 | /Users/********/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-04-21/Runner 2021-04-21 17.14.18.xcarchive |
| DSYM_OUTPUT_PATH                   | /Users/********/builds/qVPSw-s1/0/********/********/client/ios/Runner.app.dSYM.zip               |
+------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[17:22:57]: Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
+------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
|                           fastlane summary                            |
+------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                                           | Time (in s) |
+------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform                                 | 0           |
| 2    | Switch to ios build_release lane                 | 0           |
| 3    | Switch to ios certificate_release lane           | 0           |
| 4    | Switch to ios get_app_store_connect_api_key lane | 0           |
| 5    | ensure_env_vars                                  | 0           |
| 6    | app_store_connect_api_key                        | 0           |
| 7    | match                                            | 2           |
| 8    | gym                                              | 522         |
| 9    | Switch to ios get_app_store_connect_api_key lane | 0           |
| 10   | ensure_env_vars                                  | 0           |
| 11   | app_store_connect_api_key                        | 0           |
|    | appstore                                         | 9           |
+------+--------------------------------------------------+-------------+
[17:22:57]: fastlane finished with errors
Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...
➡️  Metadata Path is not considered
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18321 [open] 4 
    2 weeks ago
➡️  GITLAB CI: Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/17376 [closed] 18 
    17 Feb 2021
➡️  FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash: [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/17488 [closed] 11 
    16 Jan 2021
and 53 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=Could%20not%20retrieve%20response%20as%20fastlane%20runs%20in%20non-interactive%20mode&type=Issues&utf8=✓
  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/********/builds/qVPSw-s1/0/********/********/client/ios/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/fastlane)
/Users/********/builds/qVPSw-s1/0/********/********/client/ios/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.181.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:129:in `crash!': [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode (FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this in my project by adding the `force: true` option to the `upload_to_appstore` call in our fastfile. The [Fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/upload_to_app_store/) list force as an option, but it's hidden behind a "More Options" dropdown.

Also like the other answer says you need to have the proper permissions for your API key. You need an API Key with `App Manager` permissions to create a new build, which also lets you upload the ipa. I read somewhere that `Developer` permission is enough to update the build after an `App Manager` creates it, however I haven't actually tried it.

The lane in our fastfile now looks like this:

```
lane :release_appstore do
  upload_to_app_store(
    ipa: "<ipa_path>.ipa",
    api_key_path: "<api_key_path>.json",
    force: true
  )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Which access has your API key? Try to create a new key with `App Manager` access.